# Prevent end of email from being collapsed

Tags: email, html-email, flask-mail

I'm using Flask-Mail to send email notifications for events and currently I'm encountering a problem where if two emails of the same subject end with the same thing (which is a rather niche circumstance, but definitely necessary to consider nonetheless), the ending part of the second email will be collapsed by certain mail clients (gmail, for example) that think it's a sign-off or signature or whatever. How do I prevent this?

Currently what I'm doing is generating a random sequence of letters and putting it in a `<span style="display:none">...</span>` and appending that to the email so the client thinks it's a different footer, but that feels really hacky and I want to know if there's a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, it does not seem as though gmail gives you an option to turn this off. All of the articles written on this topic suggest making your footer unique, which is exactly what you are doing.

Furthermore, this option means that the content of the email does not change at all. This seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that `<span class="randomness"></span>` works better as a footer because the email preview (when multiple emails are in a thread, some get collapsed into a preview) ignores styling, including `display: none`.

Comment: No offence but the research seems to be very limited? Google has a support page for users to turn off conversation view. @HyperNeutrino, Gmail has an option to turn off conversation view across all devices. Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Gmail which allows you to turn off conversation view.

How the grouping occurs is:

- The subject must be similar
- The sender must be a part of the thread OR in-reply-to must be used

Now to save space, Gmail condenses texts that are same, which is what you see. If you want to turn off conversation view in desktops just navigate to *setting* -- > *generals* (tab) for desktop and use the radio button select and press save.

[image]

If you are after other devices [check this link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900) out.

Comment: although this would work from a clients POV, in this case emails are being sent, not received. What was required is a way to specify some sort of header asking the email not to br collapsed. This header does not seem to exist.