# HTML email appears differently when accessed in Gmail via Chrome and Firefox. How do I prevent this?

Tags: gmail, html-email

I have an html newsletter that already appears correctly in most cases. However, I'm experiencing a strange case when opening it in Gmail. It looks fine when I open it in Firefox but in Chrome, part of the layout gets hidden behind an expand link.

[image]

I would have an easier time understanding if I were using two different email services but this is the same account viewed on two different browsers. There are no Gmail-related extensions installed on either browser so this appears to be server side. What can I do to prevent this? Thank you.

EDIT:

[Sample output](http://ninjapeps.freehostia.com/newsletter.html)

When viewed in Gmail while using Chrome and IE, the table that has the Entertainment block gets placed inside this:

```
<div>
   <div class="adm">
      <div id="q_2" class="ajR h4" data-tooltip="Hide expanded content" aria-label="Hide expanded content" aria-expanded="true">
         <div class="ajT"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="im">
      <!-- table goes here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance of seeing the code for this? It would help identify any potential changes that could be made to ensure layout parity

Comment: @jsalita Did you look at how your email looks in IE yet? You very well could get three different outputs depending on which email client you use. And we can't help you with any of them unless you post your html code so we can see for ourselves and offer suggestions and fixes.

Comment: Long shot but do you have conversation view turned on?

Comment: @Syfer Huh. Turning conversation view off fixed it.

Comment: That's what I thought. That icon is to show conversation view. I just answered something similar for another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987865/prevent-end-of-email-from-being-collapsed. This is not in our control so while testing if this happens we can live with it i guess

Answer (score 0):

We would likely need to see the code to really help you with this. Gmail is tricky, and html emails render differently depending on which client and which device you are viewing it on. You can also check out this [Gmail guide](https://www.emailonacid.com/resource/gmail-guide/?utm_source=social&utm_medium=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=LeadGen_2019) and see if it helps you fix what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but I found a similar problem, and I solved it in my case.
This similar discussion helped me a lot: [Gmail wraps certain HTML elements in a class called im](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689882/gmail-wraps-certain-html-elements-in-a-class-called-im)

In my case, the solution to fix it was that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23684130/15219724

My email is generated using node.js, so the HTML text (of the email) is formatted as a String, that contains tabulation for intending the text into the IDE, some of these tabulations were blanch spaces instead of "/t", removing them all, the issue is fixed.